# Pulling code from remote git branch, when it does not exist locally

Tags: git

When branch `B` does not exist locally, but is on the remote repo,

```
git branch
 * A

git branch -a
 * A
  remotes/origin/B
```

How can i pull `B` to my local repo? Should i `git checkout B` first? Should i `pull`, while on branch `A`?

Please help me clarify

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the local branch `b` does not exist, then `git pull` and then simply `git checkout b` and the branch will be created automatically. 
Other options would include a `git fetch origin/b`

Comment: Once i `git pull`, should i expect `B` to show up when i `git branch`? (It does not)

Comment: no, it won't show up as a branch, after you `git pull`, it's still a remote. You need to `checkout` that branch to be seen a local branch.

Comment: Downvote. I'm not new to Git but even so I can't understand the flow from your answer

Comment: Yeah, I think git behavior maybe changed over time.  This solution does not work.  You have to explicitly check out the local and associate it with the remote, as @tee mentions with this `git checkout -b B origin/B` answer.

Answer (score 31):

Fetch all remote branches without merging anything:

```
git fetch
```

Then create a local branch (B) from the remote (origin/B) & checkout that branch to switch to it:

```
git checkout -b B origin/B
```

Then you're in branch B & you can pull in A:

```
git pull origin A
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to do:

```
git checkout -b B origin/B
```

to create the local branch from the remote.

Comment: This is old school git and more than is needed. `git checkout B` is sufficient these days.

Comment: @BillDoor git checkout B will create a branch new branch called B but it will not point to the remote branch origin/B. This is my experience on git version 2.16.2.windows.1

Answer (score -1):

Helpful git tips:

To get a remote branch to local repository, Use IDE pull/fetch options or below command:

`git pull <remote_branch_name> <local_branch_name>`

This will create a local branch, Example master.

To checkout a local branch to the current directory.

```
git checkout master .
```

This will get you project into the current working directory.